How to remove <xsi:type="xsd:string"> on XML from C#
I'm trying to consume a SOAP service from C#, there is an attribute defined as object but I have no way to pass it correctly.
If I import System.Xml and create the XML, when passing the XMLDoc.OuterString, and parse the XML that I send to SOAP, it adds the xsi:type property to the XML tag, and returns a Validation error.
If I use an object and pass it directly, it tells me that it could not be serialized correctly. If I serialize the object and pass the XML as String, I get a validation error again.
With System.XML:
XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
XmlNode nameNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Name");
XmlNode genderNode = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Gender");
genderNode.InnerText = "M";
nameNode.AppendChild(genderNode);
xmlDoc.AppendChild(nameNode);

//this is object item defined on wsdl.
p_SolicitudTransmision[0].Item = xmlDoc.OuterXml; //the value is <name><gender>M</gender></name>

(this string value is ok, but when I analyze the request int Microsoft Service Trace Viewer, the value is:
<data **xsi:type="xsd:string"**> 
<name>
<gender>M</gender>
</name>
</data>

I need to remove this xsi type because when I try to use webservice on SOAPUI without this type, it works.
I receive this when I launch my request.
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <soapenv:Fault>
         <faultcode xmlns:soap-env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">soap-env:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Validation error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'xsd:string' as a QName: the prefix 'xsd' is not declared.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
            <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-elt.4.1: The value 'xsd:string' of attribute 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance,type' of element 'DatosEspecificos' is not a valid QName.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
            <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">UndeclaredPrefix: Cannot resolve 'xsd:string' as a QName: the prefix 'xsd' is not declared.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
            <spring-ws:ValidationError xmlns:spring-ws="http://springframework.org/spring-ws">cvc-attribute.3: The value 'xsd:string' of attribute 'xsi:type' on element 'DatosEspecificos' is not valid with respect to its type, 'QName'.</spring-ws:ValidationError>
         </detail>
      </soapenv:Fault>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>


They use Java and says all it working good, so in .NET they can't help me. I need to develope on .NET because my company only works with .NET, but i don't have idea about what can i do. If I try to send the request from SoapUI, it works correctly. But I don't know how to replicate the request on C#.NET.

p_SolicitudTransmision[0].Item = xmlDoc.OuterXml; should be just p_SolicitudTransmision[0].Item = xmlDoc; you don't want to pass the XML entitization, you want to get the actual XML document.

@jdweng The XML structure is valid, but when making the request I receive a "Validation Error". I update my post adding the response i receive.

@Charlieface That contradicts the "If I use an object and pass it directly, it tells me that it could not be serialized correctly."

@AdrianTorneroOrtiz Does that object come with instructions on how to prepare the XML you are passing to it? Are you supposed to pass e.g. <name xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">...</name>?

Finally I added a MessageInspector to stop the request before making it and modify the XML. It may not be the cleanest way, but without having direct access to the schema and not knowing why it generates the wrong XML when assigning the attributes, it is difficult to give another solution.

The  envelope xsd has following :
<xs:complexType name="Fault" final="extension">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation> Fault reporting structure </xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="faultcode" type="xs:QName"/>
<xs:element name="faultstring" type="xs:string"/>
<xs:element name="faultactor" type="xs:anyURI" minOccurs="0"/>
<xs:element name="detail" type="tns:detail" minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

I think the faultcode is the issue.
